# addActionListener doesn't work I got an error on the .Handler

Tags: java, swing

I've been doing Java for a while now and I have a quite an odd error coming up. I've been looking on Google and Stackoverflow but didn't really find a solution unfortunately.

Error: [image]

If anyone can help me out here I would gladly appreciate it thanks for your time people take care.

Comment: Don't call `setSize` on the frame, use `pack` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class **k**nopHandler starts lowercase while you call new **K**nopHandler, just a typo maybe?
Next time please paste formatted code on the forums instead of providing link.

Comment: Wow really? ALl that time for just a lowecase letter? According to the book I'm working from it was a uppercase K. Anyway thanks it did the trick!

Comment: Yeah sure, I tried doing it before but wasn't able to due to the time limit. Thanks again.